# HTTPS on Windows 8 doesn't work for some users

Tags: windows-8, tcp, https

I have an issue on our home PC where some users (namely our kids) cannot load HTTPS sites. Instead, they run into a ERR_TIMED_OUT. Weird enough, if I start Fiddler to trace what's going on, HTTPS works. Once I close Fiddler, it's back to the timeout.

There was once the kid monitoring software "KidsWatch" installed on the computer, which allowed to disable port 443. I had once disabled 443, then re-enabled it, then uninstalled KidsWatch.

Now I'm wondering where to look. It's clearly not a firewall issue, as the use with fiddler shows. Are there any registry keys I should look at?

Thanks and best regards
Simon

Comment: In the meantime I've found that the issue is caused by Windows Family Safety, probably from the filter introduced by [KB2965142](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2965142/en-us). Disabling FS entirely makes the effect go away, but enabling FS with web filtering 'allow all' still shows the problem. I kinda feel it might have to do with some updates reg. Heartbleed and/or Poodle, but still. Does anyone have this issue too? Any workarounds?

Comment: I've found thw the issue to be the combination of the Windows Family Safety SSL filter along with the Bitdefender Total Security 2015 SSL filter. Not sure yet though what the final solution is..